# How to ask library to use its internal function in case same function exist in other libs

Tags: c, linker

I have a `C` program using two `libraries` libA and libB. The problem is; both the libraries have list_delete function which is a compiler error. By writing these lines I am able to compile and link my code successfully.

```
#undef list_delete
#define list_delete mysql_list_delete
```

After this I am able to call list_delete function of libA in my code. But when I call any function (other than list_delete) of libB which internally call list_delete function which happen to be libA's list_delete function.

Why? libB should call list_delete function internally not libA's list_function.

Question is how I can tell libB library to use its own list_delete function (keep in mind my program is using list_delete function of libA)

Comment: Are your libraries static or dynamic (.dll, .so, .dylib)? One way would be to declare libB's `list_delete` as `static`. That will require functions that use it to be in the same compilation unit since its symbol is not exported.

Comment: Libraries are so. I don't have control over libraries because these are third party libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading library using dlopen with RTLD_DEEPBIND solved the problem.

dlopen("libB", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND);

`RTLD_DEEPBIND (since glibc 2.3.4)
Place the lookup scope of the symbols in this library ahead of the global scope.  This means that a self-contained library will use its  own symbols in preference to global symbols with the same name contained in libraries that have already been loaded.  This flag is not specified in POSIX.1-2001.`

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if both libraries are being linked to statically.  The linker sees a `list_delete` symbol in both obj files and has to pick which one ends up in the final executable.

To avoid that, you need to either:

1. re-write and re-compile one or both libraries to use different names for their respective `list_delete()` functions.
2. change your app to link to the libraries dynamically instead of statically, then they cannot see each other's functions and will not conflict anymore.

Comment: I am not the owner of both the libraries so the changing function name is out of the question. I am linking my code staticaly with libA and dynamically with libB.

Comment: If libB is linked dynamically, it is an external module and thus cannot be calling libA's functions that are linked statically into your app, unless libB itself uses libA internally, in which case it would be using its own copy of libA, not the copy used by your app.

Comment: That is my understanding, but libB is calling libA function.By the its only happening on Linux (Ubuntu,  gcc). The same code works fine on OSX

Comment: Sorry one correction both the libraries are dynamically linked.